# Bumblebee-Status display problems

Tags: fonts, bumblebee, i3-wm

For my i3 I use bumblebee-status as the status bar. I want to use it's solarized powerline theme but the arrows are not displayed correctly
[image: Bumblebee-Status-Bar]
As you can see the arrows are not connected to their text.

I remember having such problems in my shell when I used a wrong font, but I think I am using the correct font here. 
My `.i3/config`:

```
bar {
    font pango:"DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline" 10
    position top
    tray_output none
    status_command bumblebee-status -m xrandr nic disk:root disk:home 
    battery pasink pasource date time -p root.path=/ home.path=/home/ time.format="%H:%M" date.format="%a, %d.%m.%Y" battery.device=BAT1 -t solarized-powerline
}
```

I tried using different powerline-fonts but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file in the bumblebee-status/themes/.json , change the separator block width from 0 to a negative value, mine is set to -4.

```
"defaults": {
    "warning": {
        "fg": "#1d2021",
        "bg": "#d79921"
    },
    "critical": {
        "fg": "#fbf1c7",
        "bg": "#cc241d"
    },
    "default-separators": false,
    "separator-block-width": -4
},
```